# How to use recursion to create a searies of substrings in java

Tags: java, string, recursion

So, the task is to create a string that makes a progression throughout the letters of a string, returning a substring progressively longer. 
For example if the input is Book, the answer would be: BBoBooBook . For the input Soup the method would return SSoSouSoup. I want to write it recursively. In my current method I receive no error but at the same time no anwer from the compiler.

```
public static String stringProgression(String str) {
        int index = 1;
        String result = "";
        if (str.length() == 0) {
            return "" ;
        } else while (index <= str.length()); {
                result = result + stringExplosion(str.substring(0, index));
                index++;
        } 
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What is `stringExplosion`?

Comment: The semicolon at `while (index <= str.length());` is probably a typo. If `index<str.length()`, that becomes `while(true);` so the loop never ends.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are using two different method names, `stringProgression` and `stringExplosion`.

Further, you have a `while` loop with a semicolon, `while (index <= str.length());` which forms an empty loop. Since `index` doesn’t change in this empty loop, it will be an infinite loop when the condition is fulfilled.

Generally, a `while` loop contradicts the intent to have a recursive solution.

To find a recursive solution to a problem, you have to find the self-similarity in it. I.e. when you look at the intended result for `Book`, `BBoBooBook`, you can recognize that the beginning, `BBoBoo` is the right result for the string `Boo`, and `BBo` is the right result for `Bo`. So, the original string has to be appended to the result of a recursive evaluation of the substring:

```
public static String stringProgression(String str) {
    if(str.isEmpty()) {
        return str;
    }
    return stringProgression(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1)) + str;
}
```

An alternative, shorter syntax for the same is:

```
public static String stringProgression(String str) {
    return str.isEmpty()? str: stringProgression(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1)) + str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one:

```java
    private static String doStringProgression(String str, String res, int length) {
        if(length > str.length()) {
            return res;
        }
        return doStringProgression(str, res + str.substring(0, length), length + 1);
    }
```

And you can call the method with input like in the following example:

```java
    public static String stringProgression(String str) {
        return doStringProgression(str, "", 1);
    }
```